# How to add css text formatting to javascript push errors?

Tags: javascript, css

can anyone show me how to add css text formatting to a javascript push error?
for instance if i want `margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;` added to

```
errors.push("You did not complete Company Name");
```

my javascript code:

```
<script>
function displayErrors(errors){
    var container = document.getElementById("alertBox2");
    var html = "<ul>";

    for(var i=0; i<errors.length; i++){
        html += "<li>" + errors[i] + "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";

    container.innerHTML = html;
    container.style.display = "block";
}

function validateForm(){
    var cname = document.forms["myForm"]["cname"].value;
    var creg= document.forms["myForm"]["creg"].value;
    var address= document.forms["myForm"]["address"].value;
    var post= document.forms["myForm"]["post"].value;
    var contactn= document.forms["myForm"]["contactn"].value;
    var contactt= document.forms["myForm"]["contactt"].value;
    var email= document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;

    var errors = [];

     if(cname == ""){
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
   document.getElementById("alertBox").style.display='block';
        errors.push("You did not complete Company Name");
    }

    if(errors.length > 0){
        displayErrors(errors);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Uh, like this `html += "<li style="....">" + errors[i] + "</li>";`? Or better yet, `html += "<li class="....">" + errors[i] + "</li>";`

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the following part of your Javascript:

```
for(var i=0; i<errors.length; i++){
    html += "<li class='error'>" + errors[i] + "</li>";
}
```

Then in your CSS add:

```
.error{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

This will also help separate style and content.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
errors.push("<span style='margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;'>You did not complete Company Name</span>");
```